# i can't open office in iis7

Tags: c#, windows, iis

I create post in the IIS Forum but they Can't resolve it

I in my project use of this code in button:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); 

var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "New" + ".docx");

object fileName = path;
object readOnly = false;
object startIndex = 0;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

WordApp.Visible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add();
```

I in visual studio when click on button,to be open word office but when i published on iis7, when i click on button, don't open word office

Comment: Don't do this; it won't work well.

Comment: Are you trying to run Word from an ASP.NET application on the server? @SLaks, why do you say that it won't work well? It won't work at all :-) Why giving some false hopes to the OP :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I said that before I realized that he wants UI.  If you try very hard, you can do a little bit of Word automation (without UI) on a server (no, I haven't tried)

Comment: @SLaks, me neither I haven't tried. Why would I want to hurt myself :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to create a new document for the user.

That cannot possibly work, since your code runs on the **server**.